# What can I do in my React microfrontend project so that I do not need to "npm start" for every dependent microproject

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, micro-frontend

So, I am new to microfronteds. I have built a microfrontend project watching tutorials. This is the structure.

```
demo
  |--container
  |--app1
  |--app2
  |--app3
```

`container`, `app1`, `app2` and `app3` are microfrontend projects and works fine independently and also after integrating. container app is to bring together `app1`, `app2` and `app3` and switch between them using routes.

The problem is that when I want to see container output with `app1`,`app2`,`app3`. I have to first "`npm start`" all those projects and then do the same for container. Is there a way that I have to use "`npm start`" only once. Note: I have researched a bit myself too but I don't want to use readymade stuffs like `nx`, `lerna`, `bit` etc. Something only react or node based is preferable. Also if possible give only hints/resources and not whole solution.

Comment: You can try a combination of yarn workspaces and/or [gulpjs](https://gulpjs.com/). With yarn workspaces, you can have a workspace-level package.json which can be a useful place to have your `gulp start` command. Gulpjs then allows you to create that start command using something like `gulp.parallel`, which can start a bunch of commands to run at the same time. I've used this combination in the past, and it greatly simplifies the process of starting multiple tasks at once, without cluttering your package.json with shell quotes and escapes just to fit multiple commands in one `start` script

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom node script like this:

```js
import child_process from 'child_process';
import util from 'util';
const spawn = util.promisify(child_process.spawn);

const startApp = (app) =>
    spawn('npm', ['start'], {
        env: { ...process.env },
        cwd: app,
        stdio: 'inherit',
    });

await Promise.all([
    startApp('container'),
    startApp('app1'),
    startApp('app2'),
    startApp('app3'),
]);
```

Only native NodeJS dependencies are used above. Since ESM is used above, make sure to name it with an ".mjs" extension. Will not work with an outdated NodeJS version. E.g. `start-all.mjs`.

If you placed it one level above all apps, i.e. in your "demo" directory then you can run it using `node start-all.mjs` and all starting in parallel and are running.